# Multiple javascripts not collaborating together properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here, I'm a self-taught web designer who frankly have no knowledge of any javascript or jquery. However, I'm able to follow instructions and use plug-ins of course :)

I've been trying to search for a solution for the problem I'm experiencing currently.

I have a multiple js plug-ins and I think some of them are overlapping and cancelling each other out at the moment.

The following is what I have between < /body> and < /html>

*Sorry, I tried posting the codes but got a warning telling me that they were from another domain, which is blocked / failed to load. So here's a screenshot image file!

```
http://i.imgur.com/QHBCNjM.jpg
```

All of these were working properly until I added the Content Switcher plug-in (source: https://github.com/cheynewallace/jquery-content-panel-switcher/tree/master/demo%20and%20instructions)

When I load the page, MouseOn caption plug-in and Lytebox plug-in work fine. But the moment I trigger the Content Switch plug-in, the aforementioned plug-ins become disabled.

Should I give up the content switcher? I've tried other plug-ins and non-javascript methods, but this works and fits my purpose the best so far.. So I'm a little agitated :(

If someone could help, that would save my day.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, you seem to have more than one jquery script referenced. Maybe getting rid of some will help